# How Do I Fetch in Visual Studio 2019 For Mac?

Tags: git, visual-studio-mac

How can I git fetch only in Visual Studio 2019 for Mac (Version 8.8.8 (build 12)), so I can see new branches and new commits in my current branch?  I don't see an option in Version Control menu...?  Only Pull... ?

Using repo on Azure DevOps, so not so easy to use with sourcetree or some other free git client on mac.

[image]

Comment: What happens if you click `Manage Branches and Remotes`?

Comment: You might consider VSCode + Git Graph, https://ardalis.com/git-graph-visualizes-branches-in-vs-code-for-free/ A much better cross platform setup than things like SourceTree. BTW, VS for Mac didn't implement too many Git features.

Comment: Manage Branches  and Remotes - Remote Sources, select remote, then click Fetch?